# PDO Update Statement Not Working

Tags: php, pdo

I've browsed the web quite a bit before asking here; I noticed that some people have the same problem as me, but none of the answers that were given to the others didn't solve my problem, so....

I have a basic PDO Update Statement inside a public function:

```
 public function editRank($name, $rank){
$query = "UPDATE `chat_mod` SET `chat_mod_rank` = :rank WHERE `chat_mod_ign` = :username";
$prepare = $this->_db->prepare($query);
$array = array(
    ':rank'     => $rank,
    ':username' => $name
);

try {
    $prepare->execute($array);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    return false;
}
return true; // If no PDO Exception is thrown..
```

}

No exception is thrown, so the function always returns true; but the rows are not being updated. Yes, I've checked that the rows are named properly and the values are not nulls.

Thanks,
Tom.

P.S Other queries like Select, Add & Delete work fine.

Comment: Are you sure that your $name exists in the database? An update query can succeed but update 0 rows if no rows match

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure, I even copied the username directly from a select to make sure I'm not typing anything incorrectly.

Comment: So if you echo out your query and run it on command line or phpmyadmin it works?

Comment: That's the problem, I'm coding it for a client and I don't have direct access to PHPMyAdmin, so I can't fully debug it.

Comment: Well the problem is we can even less debug it. I can't see anything wrong with the information provided, but its normally the information that is not provided that causes the problem. Whats the db structure?

Comment: The table structure consists `chat_mod_ign`, `chat_mod_id`, `chat_mod_alias` and `chat_mod_actions`.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is just a PHP program. Are you sure you can't run PHP programs on the host?

Comment: I don't have the access to the SQL details; I only know the structure and can access anything in the DB. The SQL info is stored in a file which I cannot access.

Comment: Well it appears you are trying to set a column that does not exist in the db. `chat_mod_rank`, so again I say it is the info not included that is causing the problem

Comment: Ah my bad it does exist, I simply forgot to mention it. PDO doesn't return an error... Maybe it might be related to the Table's privileges? I'm really out of ideas.

Comment: if you have no access to database structure, what makes you say `"Yes, I've checked that the rows are named properly and the values are not nulls."`? By what means you did such checking?

Comment: Using a SELECT query, I've received the table structure and it's values. I'm 100% positive my query isn't broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are catching PDO exceptions but did you tell PDO to throw them?

To make PDO throw exceptions you have to configure [PDO errmode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). Note that setting this mode as a connection option will let PDO throw exceptions on connection errors too, which is very important.
So, here is an example for creating a PDO connection right way:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    // other options 
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Connecting this way, you will be always notified of all database errors, occurred during query execution. Note that you have to be able to see PHP errors in general. On a live site you have to peek into error logs, so, settings have to be

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
```

while on a local development server it's ok to make errors on screen:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

and of course you should never ever use error suppression operator (`@`) in front of your PDO statements.

Also, due to many bad examples telling you to wrap every PDO statement into `try..catch` block, I have to make a distinct note:

> **DO NOT use try..catch operator just to echo an error message.** Uncaught exception is already excellent for this purpose, as it will act just the same way as other PHP errors - so, you can define the behavior using site-wide settings - so, **you will have your error message without this useless code.** *While unconditionally echoed error message may reveal some sensitive information to a potential attacker, yet confuse a honest visitor.*
>
> - A [custom exception handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) could be added later, but not required. Especially for new users, it is recommended to use unhandled exceptions, as they are extremely informative, helpful and secure.
> - Use `try..catch` only if you are going to handle the error itself - say, to rollback a transaction.